# cobol calling a C function with a long parameter

Tags: c, function, cobol

I have a function defined in C

```
bool moveTable(char * ,  long);
```

which is being invoked from cobol, when it is called from cobol, i can see it passing a correct value of long into the moveTable function, but when the control passes to C and i do a printf inside moveTable, for some reason, i am getting a garbage negative value such as -178634436. I believe it cant be a storage issue, because on cobol the number passed to long is 5264011, which can be saved inside a long.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: This is how the field is defined in cobol, which is passed to moveTable function long parameter.

```
   10  ATPRM-TRT-ACCT-ID           PIC S9(08) COMP-5.
```

Comment: *"Any suggestion?"*... yeh... ***Show your code!*** Otherwise we're all just shootin' in the dark.

Comment: Search what are the integer sizes in cobol (Specificaly the cobol `long` size) and then select the proper standard size integral type of `stdint.h` (`int8_t,int16_t,int32_t,` etc)

Comment: Which COBOL compiler and OS are you using?

Comment: OS is AIX Unix and cobol compiler i m not sure about.

Comment: The cobol compiler is microfocus cobol  . Strangely when i use int16_t or int8_t, it gives me a positive belieavable value, but still not correct. But as soon as i make it a int32_t, int or long i get a huge negative garbage value.

Comment: OK, thanks. Can you update your question with all the information, then we can delete the comments and keep it tidy. Can you also show the CALL to the function, and the code in the C function which gives you the negative value, and the values for the other definitions. Correct input, then all the outputs that you get.

Comment: possibly the `char *` is not the expected size, or there is a calling convention mismatch. To help diagnose this, can you please post the exact values you are sending and the exact garbage that you receive?  Also can you try without the `char *` arg?

Comment: Can you show exactly what is passed and what is received.

Comment: If possible, show the hex values of what the C program thinks it has. Try with a simple cut-down program where the `COMP-5` is defined at the `01`-level. In the C program also show the length of the `long` then we'll know for that compiler.

Comment: We're talking Big Endian, or Most Significant Byte, for the byte-order of that COMP-5 on AIX (PowerPC). I can't imagine that the C compiler being used is knowing otherwise... but my C isn't anywhere near good enough for real imagining (I can spell it, given a couple of attempts). With the example, C treating it as Little Endian would get negative, but I really can't believe that's the answer :-)

Comment: GNU Cobol has an extension datatype  `BINARY-C-LONG`, guaranteed to be a native C `long`, which doesn't always match the COBOL standard `BINARY-LONG` when cross compiling for 32bit, 64bit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

isn't

```
 10  ATPRM-TRT-ACCT-ID           PIC S9(08) COMP-5.
```

a **4 byte** integer while **long** can be either 4 or 8 byte integer ??? depending in implementation.

shouldn't it be

```
 10  ATPRM-TRT-ACCT-ID           PIC S9(17) COMP-5.
```

This is probably not be the answer, but it is an issue. Also does C expect any word alignment ???

Comment: If you see the comments on the other answer, I doubt if `long` is eight bytes. If it were, what would `long long` be? If alignment was a problem, wouldn't it crash, rather than give a result? It can't say "I'll use that address but change it a little", can it? How does the example value become negative?

Comment: if long in C is at least 32 bits (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) if it where an 8 byte little-ending the 4 following bytes would determine the sign

Comment: Certainly, if there is a length mismatch such that the C is longer and it is Little Endian, data outside the field is determining the sign. If accurately described to us, it is AIX running on a PowerPC (or predecessor) and is Big Endian, so even with a length mismatch, if there were, the actual data is determining the sign (most significant bit). The COMP-5 field is four bytes, everything leads me to think (and I can certainly be wrong) that the `long` is four bytes in this program.

Answer (score -1):

Try using an int. If that does not work, then remove the other char * and just pass value with either as int or long and see if it makes a difference. I'd stick to integers when dealing with cross systems or strings and then convert numbers into long.  That has no basis from my research. I was simply remembering long long rather that int versus long. In AIX, int and long will most likely be the same size.

So if nothing works, try passing the number as string (char * or char array) whichever works....

See this http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cbl.doc%2Fcpari09.htm

Also if you can change the type S9(9).. see this

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cbl.doc%2Ftpsubw20.htm

Comment: How long is a long? Perhaps curiously the COBOL compiler is Micro Focus (despite IBM having a COBOL compiler for AIX). The field definition is four bytes (32 bits), signed, allowing the full binary value. Can't change that, so how would that be in C?

Comment: I'd assume AIX supports 64 bit.  I don't have anything to go by without googling. A Long is usually double the size of int so an int is usually 4 bytes in modern architectures and will probably be 8 bytes in AIX. Of course that's speculation based on reading there is COBOL and AIX involved. One needs proper version strings of compiler and operating system as well as the C and the Cobol code. Having none of the above, I have suggested trying a few different troubleshooting techniques if I was him. It's impossible to answer this question without a lot information.

Comment: Looks like I am wrong, I looked up 64 bit and int is the same as long and now that I take some time to think about it, I am wrong since 64 bit int supports the date to extend beyond 20.. Have not been playing with Unix and C for a while. I was thinking long long rather than long when I said double size...

Comment: Jeepers, eight bytes would be a vast :-) You're right, we don't have the info. If it was just a size mismatch, the result from the C program would have been more huge, and not negative.

Comment: My guess is char *. I am not sure you can declare on the c that way even if you pass a string. It has to be an exact size so that when the call happens, the stack can be properly read. I am not sure cobol puts a null at end of strings like C :)

Comment: No, COBOL isn't going to "terminate", it doesn't have strings, fixed-length fields. The example code in the AIX link you provided doesn't user `char *`. I don't so much know why you're getting downvotes. Next time use comments on the question to get more information/suggest things, and an answer when you have something for real. Still, OP should be trying things for themselves, so a little counter to the downvotes coming your way.